# Async functions not waiting inside a forEach loop

Tags: javascript, foreach, async-await

I have a call to my async function inside a forEach loop, like this:

```
foo {
    list.forEach(function( field ) {        
        populateValues( field );
    });

    // here my list is returned incomplete
    return list;
}

populateValues = async function ( field ) {
    if ( field.someProp === true ) {
        fields.val = await somePromise();
    }
}

somePromise = function() {
    return new Promise( resolve => {
        fetchMyAPIExample().then( function( value ) {
            resolve( value );
        }
    }
}
```

populateValues() waits correctly my promise, but foo() doesn't wait populateValues to return the list, so it return my list incomplete.

Comment: anyway, nothing here modifies the var `list`, so correcting this won't be enough, your list will stay the same. We also have a reference to `fields` that is not declared here

Comment: @kaddath no, field.val = ...

Comment: @Jonasw i guess this is what was intended, but this won't really help too, as `field` in his code is a string with the property name, not the property itself. But you corrected allright in your answer i guess

Comment: @kaddath no, thats not jquerys forEach.

Comment: ah yes, you're right ^^ should be careful about that in the future!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to await there too, which doesnt work with forEach but with for..of :

```
async function foo(){
  for(var field of list){        
    await populateValues( field );
  }
  return list
}
```

Or if you want to enable racing:

```
function foo(){
  return Promise.all(
    list.map( field => populateValues( field ))
  ).then(_=>list);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Being that each of the function calls to *populateValues()* is async, the function *foo* doesn't wait to return the *list* object.

You can make *foo* await the results of *populateValues* to get the response you expect.